# I am constantly getting errors in Facebook Business Manager

Tags: facebook, ads

When doing my Facebook Ad exercises for new hires, I keep getting error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the Ads Manager.
At the top, right-hand side there are three dots ...
Click on the three dots, and select 'Reset Ads Manager.'